# Connection is closed

Tags: connection, connection-pooling

am working on **dbcp** connection pooling which I am trying to implement in an existing Java application(implemented in struts). I have noticed that in my java application none of the connections are closed. I am now trying to close those connections. The problem is whenever I use `connection.close()` I am getting an *exception*. Following is the **error**. Kindly help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

> java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(PoolingDataSource.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:312)
>     at .....................

Comment: Do you have the validation query specified?

Comment: No I don't have any.

Comment: Hope [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Preventing_dB_connection_pool_leaks) will help you.

Comment: Thanks chinmayan for your reply.Just to get clarification...do I need to use connection.close if I am configuring removeAbandoned="true" etc in my xml file.